# Printing "man", "eater" recursively depending on user input

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to achieve this result recursively

Results should be:

> print_3(1)
>
> man
>
> print_3(3)
>
> man
>
> eater
>
> man

tried this but it does do it exactly

```
def print_3(n):
    if n == 1:
        return ("man")
    elif n == None:
        return " "
    elif n %2 == 0:
        return ("eater") 
    else:
        return print_3(n) + print_3(n - 1)


print(print_3(4))
```

Comment: it it just supposed to alternate between the two words for `n` times?

Comment: yes. thats how it should operate.

Comment: Do you have to return? Can you not return and just print?

Comment: Whichever way is fine. Once it is done recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
def print_3(n, even):
if n == 1:
    print("man" if not even else "eater")
else:
    print(["man", "eater"][n % 2 == 0 if not even else n % 2 != 0])
    print_3(n-1, even)

print_3(4, even=True)
```

Basically, it uses the parity of `n` to determine which string to print. The recursion is provided by the `print_3(n-1, even)`.

**Note**
Even though the code above does use recursion, the way it uses it is at least unusual. Generally, recursion is used to decompose a big problem into multiple subproblems, solve each subproblem and keep track of their results in order to build the solution to the original problem later on. In this case, the intermediate results are not stored (note the absence of the return + assignement statement) because they are not important. To know which term to print, it is sufficient to look at the parity of n.

Comment: intersting. what does `[some] [something]` does. Can you explain that concept.

Comment: Sure. `[something]` is a condition. When it evaluates `true`, python converts that `true` into `1`. Then, you have `["man", "eater"][1]` which obviously returns `"eater"` since it is the element at index `1` of that list. On the contrary, it the condition evaluates to `false`, i.e. `0`, then the element at index `0` is returned, that is `"man"`.

Comment: it works app to 3. but beyond it doesn't print what its expected. call the function with 4 and world, hello, world, hello

Comment: It doesn't work for even numbers. So want to get >> "man" "eater"

Comment: You need to add a flag, to tell it to start from man or eater. I edited my answer see if it works now.